# A couple questions on radical extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

1. This is vague, but perhaps someone will be able to shed some light on basic techniques:
   How would one go about proving an extension is not radical?
2. What is the relationship between primitive roots of 1 and radical extensions? Does every radical extension contain a primitive root of 1? I'm not really sure if there is a connection here, but some of my lecture notes seem to indicate there might be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) One proves that an extension is radical by expressing elements that generate the extension in terms of radicals. That is, they can be expressed in terms of elements of the ground field, $+,-,\times,\div$ and radicals. If you can write down elements of this form, you can then get a decomposition series for the Galois group (of the Galois closure of) your extension (you may also need to adjoin some roots of $1$ during this process). So every radical extension is solvable. I can't get into the proof here but you can find it in your favorite book on abstract algebra or Galois theory.

2) The Kronecker-Weber theorem states that every abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$ is a subextension of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$, where $\zeta_n$ denotes a primitive $n$th root of $1$. Suppose you have a radical extension of $\mathbb Q$ with group $G$. Since every radical extension is solvable, there is a normal subgroup $N$ so that $G/N$ is abelian. Thus by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, the fixed field of $N$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$, and thus contained inside some cyclotomic extension. But that is as much as you can say: For example, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q$ is abelian (and thus solvable), and contained inside some cyclotomic extension (in fact it is contained in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$), but it is not itself a cyclotomic extension. On the other hand, $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4] 2)$ has the dihedral group of order $8$ as its Galois group, so it is solvable but not abelian, and therefore is not contained in any cyclotomic extension, although the intersection with some cyclotomic field, $\mathbb Q(i)$, is more than just $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks for the information! That helps.

Comment: In 1) your statement is not quite correct. If the Galois group is solvable then the extension doesn't have to be radical. All you know if that the extension is contained in some radical extension. For example all Galois extension of degree 3 over Q are not radical even though the Galois groups is clearly solvable

Comment: @user39947 Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I'll amend the post now.